# How do I store (and find) a string with a wildcard in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store an IP address with a wildcard in it, like 10.0.%.1. Then, I want anyone with an IP address in the allowed range (10.0.0-255.1) to be found from my query.

Could you guys please help me? I've tried storing 10.0.%.1 but can't find it with a LIKE query (I don't even know if that's the way to do it - probably not).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you store the values with % ?

Comment: Use a number greater than 255(like `350`) and replace it with a wildcard in php?

Comment: How do you want to use your wildcard ? Would 10.0.1%.1 and 10.% be considered as valid too ?

Comment: Yeah, 10.0.% would probably do it, too. I don't know the IP addresses except for the first sections, whatever they're called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you save the ip addresses as 4 integers in the database like so:

```
IPpart1 IPpart2 IPpart3 IPpart4
-------------------------------
127     0       0       1
```

And make them nullable. (NULL is going to be our wildcard)

You can then do a query on the db like this:

```
SELECT * FROM iptable WHERE (IPpart1 IS NULL OR IPpart1 = '$firstpart') AND (IPpart2 IS NULL OR IPpart2 = '$secondpart') AND (IPpart3 IS NULL OR IPpart3 = '$thirdpart') AND (IPpart4 IS NULL OR IPpart4 = '$fourthpart')
```

It is a little bit verbose bit it gets the job done.

It should even be possible to construct a temporary table with that structure from a normal IP field, but that would be a lot of overhead if you have many requests.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach - this worked great for me and was simple enough to set up.

Answer (score 3):

Convert IP addresses to 32 bit integers and make a column for the address and the mask.  You can use `INET_NTOA()` and `INET_ATON()` functions.  Your 10.0.%.1 range can be expressed as network 10.0.0.1 with a mask of 255.255.0.255.  To see if a given IP address matches this network, you apply the mask to the IP address, and compare it to the network address.  If they match, the address is in the network.  For example, if you want to test 10.0.4.1, you apply the mask to it using bitwise AND:

```
10.0.4.1 & 255.255.0.255 = 10.0.0.1
```

This matches your network address, so this IP is in the network.

You can store this network in your table like this (ip and mask are integers):

```
CREATE TABLE networks (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ip INT, mask INT);

INSERT INTO networks (ip, mask)
VALUES (INET_ATON('10.0.0.1'), INET_ATON('255.255.0.255'));
```

You can find if a given IP (10.0.23.1) matches like this:

```
SELECT * FROM networks
WHERE ip & mask = INET_ATON('10.0.23.1') & mask
```

This will select the IPs as integers though, if you want them human readable:

```
SELECT id, INET_NTOA(ip) AS ipstring, INET_NTOA(mask) AS maskstring
FROM networks
WHERE ip & mask = INET_ATON('10.0.23.1') & mask
```

This allows you to test if a single given IP address matches a network.  If you want to test a range of IPs, you'd have to apply the mask to each one in the range and test each one as a above.  You can do it in a single query, it'll just have to list every IP address you're testing.

Comment: Interesting take, is it possible to query for a range of IP's like this? say range from `10.0.12.1` to `10.0.123.2` if you use `BETWEEN int1 AND int2`?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You'd have to apply the mask to each IP address in the range and then compare that to the network address.  This is because the network mask can have holes in it, and even if both ends of your range are in the network, some addresses in the middle of the range might not be.  For example, if my mask was 255.255.2.255 for a 10.0.0.1 network, IPs 10.0.0.1, 10.0.4.1 and 10.0.5.1 would be in the network, but 10.0.2.1 and 10.0.3.1 would not.

Comment: Wouldn't `WHERE ip & mask BETWEEN INET_ATOM('10.0.20.1') & mask AND INET_ATOM('10.0.50.1') & mask` work then? I see no reason why it wouldn't, Worst case you'd need a join of sorts, but unless I'm missing something, it would work, right?

Comment: If your network is 10.0.0.1 with a mask of 255.255.8.255, then `ip & mask` is 10.0.0.1, `10.0.20.1 & mask` is 10.0.0.1 (matches), `10.0.50.1 & mask` is 10.0.0.1 (matches), but `10.0.30.1 & mask` is 10.0.8.1 (doesn't match.)  So even though your BETWEEN expression is true, there's an address in the middle of that range that doesn't match.

Comment: Totally awesome answer - thank you! However, it wasn't the one I used for this scenario, as I needed different ranges of IPs (both LAN and WAN IPs).

Answer (score 0):

I had a closer look on the MySQL doc pages, and I found a post there that fits your needs:

```
SELECT '10.0.0.1' AS IP0,
( SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.0.1', '.', 1 ) * 16777216 +
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.0.1', '.', 2 ),'.',-1) * 65536 +
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.0.1', '.', -2 ),'.',1) * 256 +
SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.0.1', '.', -1 )
),
'10.0.255.1' AS IP1,
    ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.255.1', '.', 1 ) * 16777216 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.255.1', '.', 2 ),'.',-1) * 65536 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.255.1', '.', -2 ),'.',1) * 256 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( '10.0.255.1', '.', -1 )
) AS IP2Num1
```

Returns a numeric value for each IP:

```
Ip:  |  10.0.0.1  | 10.0.255.1 |
--------------------------------
Num: | 167772161  | 167837441  |
```

In other words:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM bar.foobar
WHERE ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ipField, '.', 1 ) * 16777216 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( ipField, '.', 2 ),'.',-1) * 65536 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( ipField, '.', -2 ),'.',1) * 256 +
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( ipField, '.', -1 )
) BETWEEN 167772161 AND 167837441;
```

---

Well, you *could* do this:

```
WHERE ipField LIKE '10.0.%.1'
AND (CAST
       (REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipField,'.',3),
                CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipField ,'.',2),'.')
                ,'')
     AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 0 AND 255)
```

Which I tested with the following query:

```
SELECT IF ('10.0.12.1' LIKE '10.0.%.1'
       AND (CAST
             (REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX('10.0.12.1','.',3),
                 CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('10.0.12.1','.',2),'.')
              ,'')
            AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 0 AND 255),
      TRUE,
      FALSE);
```

And it returns `1`, but, honestly, that's a bit of a faff, isn't it? Why not simply:

```
WHERE ipField REGEXP '10\\.0\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.1'
```

You can tweak this expression a bit, but basically, that seems to me to be the easiest way to query for those IP addresses.
For more on MySQL string functions (which are nearly always going to be a pain to write), see [the docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Instead of using all those `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions to convert a string IP to an integer, you can just use `INET_ATON()`.

Comment: I read your answer after posting this, and voted it up - Perhaps the OP is wondering if implementing your answer requires him to alter his tables, and enables him to use `BETWEEN` to query for a range of IP's... perhaps you might want to edit your answer to reflect on that. IMO, yours is the answer, but I've given a few links here that might be of use to some ppl, but I say again: you've provided the best answer to the question at hand

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer with table schema and testing for a range of IPs.